# É necessário usar meta-tags em páginas de administração?

Tags: html, seo, html-meta-tag

É necessário ter as *meta-tags* "description", "keywords" em páginas de administração do site, já que estas não serão indexadas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Meta tags*, mesmo `description` e `keywords` podem ser úteis para outras coisas. Elas são documentadoras para seu próprio uso. Então se você tiver algum motivo para usá-las, use. Se não consegue encontrar nenhum motivo não tem porque usar.

Outras mudam o comportamento do navegador em como renderizar a página. Exemplo:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
```

Mesmo em uma página de administração isto tem alguma influência, não fundamental. Sem ela talvez sua página será renderizada de forma errada. Note que "utf-8" foi apenas um exemplo, poderia ser outros *encondigs*.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/MetaTag.html).

Outro exemplo que cria uma ação no navegador.

Você está obviamente correto que para SEO elas não servirão. Na verdade há controvérsias se o seu uso para SEO é útil de fato. O Google não as usa para a indexação em si.

Comment: OK @bigown, utilizo as meta tags sitadas acima ja para configuração (e outras para definir idiomas por exemlo), eliminarei as tags description e keywords já que elas não serão indexadas

Answer (score 5):

Acredito que na parte de administração do site as metas "Keywords" e "Description" possam ser ignoradas, mas vale a pena utilizar a meta Title para que o próprio usuário acostumado possa se localizar por ela.

Comment: Meta Title não é vista pelo usuário. Diferente da tag `<title>`, que não é meta.